# How to change the tip of line in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, line

I want to change the tip of a line in latex. For example consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[yscale=5,thick,domain=-2:2,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({\x},{exp(-\x*\x)/sqrt(2*pi)});
\draw[ultra thick] (1.3,0)--(1.3,{5*exp(-1.69)/sqrt(2*pi)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

In the output of the above lines of code, the upper tip of the straight line drawn doesn't completely match with the bell-shaped curve. This straight line is like a filled rectangle, whereas I want it to be like a filled trapezium, when zoomed. (Additionally, I would also be very happy to see any suggestion on how to draw normal density function easily, instead of specifying that manually.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `clip`. Note also that it appears worthwhile to declare a function here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=5*exp(-\x*\x)/sqrt(2*pi);}]
\begin{scope}[thick]
 \draw[clip] plot [domain=-2:2,smooth,variable=\x] ({\x},{f(\x)});
 \draw[ultra thick] (1.3,0)--(1.3,{f(1.3)+0.1});
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Everything inside the scope will be clipped.

Alternatively you can just use a plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=5*exp(-\x*\x)/sqrt(2*pi);}]
 \draw[thick] plot [domain=-2:2,smooth,variable=\x] ({\x},{f(\x)});
 \fill plot[variable=\x,domain=-8:8] 
 ({1.3cm+0.1*\x*1pt},{f(1.3+0.1*\x*1pt/1cm)*1cm})
 |- ({1.3cm-0.8pt},0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

As for the extended comments below this post: clip clips everything that comes after it in the path. So it seems to me that you might want

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=5*exp(-\x*\x)/sqrt(2*pi);}]
\begin{scope}[thick]
 \draw (-2.5,0)--(4.5,0);
 \draw plot [domain=-2:2,smooth,variable=\x] ({\x},{f(\x)});
 \clip plot [domain=-2:2,smooth,variable=\x] ({\x},{f(\x)}) -- (4.5,0) -- (-2.5,0);
 \draw[ultra thick] (1.3,0)--(1.3,{f(1.3)+0.1});
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, the first one is not working in my case, and the second one is working but I could not understand the `\fill` statement, can you please elaborate??

Comment: @Martund Could you please explain what you mean by "not working"? Did you use the code as is? What problems do you have? As for the fill, this really just fills the area under the plot that goes from `x=1.3cm-0.8pt` to `1.3cm+0.8pt` since `ultra thick` sets the line width to 1.6pt.

Comment: No, my original full code is very complex, what I posted was a MWE.

Comment: In the first method, I could not join the ultra thick line obtained to both the curve and the x-axis (I also have a thick x-axis in the graph), even if I put the draw command for x-axis in the `scope` environment.

Comment: @Martund You need to put the clip and the ultra thick line in a scope.

Comment: If I put all the three (the x-axis, ultra thick line and bell curve) in a single `scope` environment,  it is not working. Do I need to have two separate `scope` environments, one with ultra thick line and x-axis, and the other with ultra thick line and bell curve, to be clipped separately??

Comment: @Martund If you start a scope and put a `\clip` command in this scope, only stuff that is in the scope and after the `\clip` command will be clipped. You seem to have a specific use case and ask questions related to that. It would be much easier to answer these if I knew how the use case looks like explicitly.

Comment: I am telling you the exact case, I need an x-axis also in the graph, along with this bell curve and ultra thick line.

Comment: The following is not working--
```\begin{scope}[thick]
  \clip[draw] plot[domain=-2:2,smooth,variable=\x] ({\x},{f(\x)});
  \draw (-2.5,0)--(4.5,0);
        \draw[ultra thick] (1.3,0)--(1.3,{5*exp(-1.69)/sqrt(2*pi)});
        \end{scope}```

Comment: @Martund As I said, everything after the clip will be clipped, so `\begin{scope}[thick] \draw (-2.5,0)--(4.5,0); \clip[draw] plot[domain=-2:2,smooth,variable=\x] ({\x},{f(\x)});  \draw[ultra thick] (1.3,0)--(1.3,{5*exp(-1.69)/sqrt(2*pi)}); \end{scope}`, i.e. put `\draw (-2.5,0)--(4.5,0);` before the path that has the clip.

Comment: This is not working, you see. The ultra thick line is a little detached from the x-axis.

Comment: @Martund I added an example at the end of the post. Given the explicit codes I think to understand better what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is working, but can you please elaborate on how does this `\clip` command work? Usually the double colons are used to draw lines between specified points, what are they doing here, when one side is the plot of  a function?

Comment: @Martund The `-- <coordinate>` here has the same meaning as in usual paths: "insert line from the previous point to  <coordinate>". In this case, the previous point is the last point of the plot, and the coordinate is just `(4.5,0)`. (You can even merge two plots that way.) One way of finding out what happens is to  replace `\clip plot   ...` by `\draw[blue] plot ...`, which will paint the path in blue. (Of course, in the end you need to revert these debugging changes.)