# How can I change the tip of line in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, line

I want to draw following line, its tip at right), as follows:

[image: image 1] [image: image 2]

---

tex file:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) grid (1,-1);
    \draw [semithick](0.8,-0.1)--+(-0.6,-0.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I was not able to draw perfectly symmetric line inside the box and couldn't draw the tip of the line as shown above.

Could be related to: [How to change the tip of line in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542992/how-to-change-the-tip-of-line-in-tikz)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `arrows.meta` library with `Triangle Cap` to get those line tips.

[image]

I changed your `grid` to `rectangle` to get nicer corners. To place the line along the diagonal, you can draw from corner to corner and use `shorten` as in the code below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,-1);
    \draw[Triangle Cap-Triangle Cap, shorten <=2mm, shorten >=2mm] [semithick](0,-1)--++(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to center the line in the box?

Comment: Given the grid coordinates, you could use `(.2,-.8)--++(.6,.6)`, or use `(0,-1)--++(1,1)` and add `shorten <=2mm, shorten >=2mm`.

Comment: Should I write `shorten <=2mm, shorten >=2mm`inside the `draw[]`?

Comment: @alper: I edited my response.